# MySQL indexed table join on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to fix an inventory structure that has to map by two or more fields and I am stumped on the best approach.

My structure is not very important, because I can re-create as needed.
The original version was not normalized and contained only two tables.
The parts being sold in one table. Required fields: SKU, MPN, Brand, Cost
The supplier inventory in the other. Required fields: SKU, MPN, Brand, Supplier, Warehouse, Cost

The SKU and MPN may not necessarily be the same, as parts.SKU is the store's SKU and supplier.SKU is the supplier's SKU. MPN is the brand's MPN, but in some situations one supplier may use the Brand's sku for MPN, while another will use the Brand's MPN. This is where the trouble comes into play with the normalized tables.

The normalized tables I attempted split the Suppliers and Warehouse with related IDs.
A query such as this works as expected and performs at a reasonable speed:

```
SELECT * FROM parts p
JOIN warehouse w ON w.id = p.warehouse
JOIN supplier s ON s.id = w.supplier
JOIN inventory i ON i.brand = p.brand AND i.mpn = p.mpn
```

This has an index for p.mpn and runs as expected. The same code, replacing p.mpn with p.sku will return the other matched parts.
When trying to get them together by replacing `AND i.mpn =` with `AND (i.mpn = p.mpn OR i.mpn = p.sku)` the query doesn't use either index and runs so slow it never completes (I've let it run for ~2 minutes before canceling it)

To resolve this, I've attempted duplicating the above query with a UNION; This resolves the performance issue mostly, as the query runs ~2 seconds. (However, each by themselves run ~0.01 seconds)

So my question is this:
Is there a way to `JOIN on X = Y OR X = Z` while still using indexes to keep the speed?
If not, should I just go back to tables that are not normalized? (This will hurt when developing the HTML front-end for Customer Service Reps to view and modify data)
Or, do you have a suggestion on a way to structure a MySQL database to deal with the requirement of matching supplier information to store information, when different suppliers use different MPN's to represent the same one?
For example, one brand has a numerical SKU `123` and a alpha-numeric MPN `ABC`. One supplier uses MPN `123`, while another uses MPN `ABC`. For the store to match, it uses SKU `123` and MPN `ABC`
Right now, only two possible values are used, but there is potential that a third supplier may use only a UPC to match, and I would need to add that as a 3rd condition. So something that supports multiple possible match values is needed. My attempt at using a UNION would be cumbersome and even slower as the query is duplicated for each possible match condition.

I'm sure there are multiple ways to handle this, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL generally finds it difficult to use indexes when you use `OR`. You could try `i.mpn IN (p.mpn, p.sku)` but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: `UNION` is the usual workaround for this, as you've discovered.

Comment: @Barmar IN results in the same EXPLAIN path and serves no advantage.